# How to filter records from a Parquet file using Python pyarrow

Tags: python, parquet, apache-arrow

I'm trying to filter specific records from a parquet file. I'm using python pyarrow.
I managed to do it with pandas (see code below). The problem it that is takes a lot of memory for a large parquet file. I'm looking for other options - any ideas?

Thanks.

```
df = pq.read_table(INPUT_FILE).to_pandas()
df.query("id not in (%s)" % str(IDS_TO_FILTER)[1:-1], inplace=True)
pq.write_table(pa.Table.from_pandas(df), OUTPUT_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parquet file is partitioned, then you can filter by partition using the [`filter` keyword argument to `ParquetDataset`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset).  So in this particular case, it would work if your parquet files are partitioned by `id`.